# Getting not-null errors despite having a default value set.

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have the following database column:

```
 `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

With the following mapping in hibernate:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="last_modified", nullable=false, length=19)
public Date getLastModified() {
    return this.lastModified;
}
```

This has been working fine for months now but all of a sudden out of nowhere I am getting the following error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.fs.model.BrowserHistory.lastModified

So I am wondering, why is this happening all of a sudden? Is it OK if I set the lastModified field to be nullable?

Comment: Did you actually set the property? Hibernate will validate before persisting. That you defined a default in your table definition won't matter.

Comment: @Bart, No, it is a DB generated property so I shouldn't have to set it. I think I found a solution in the hibernate documentation and have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that database generated columns need some specific annotations:

```
@Column(name="last_modified", nullable=false, length=19, insertable=false, updatable=false)
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
```

We are trying this out now but I think it will fix the issue.

Comment: Still testing, but it seems like it has fixed the issue. The odd thing was the issue was sporadic and not consistent so I want to wait a day or two before marking an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you would like to record the modification timestamp. To avoid setting it manually (or not setting it and getting errors) you can use lifecycle callbacks:

```
@PrePersist
public void updateTimestamps() {
    lastModified = new Date();
}
```